# Flex compiler & size optimization

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

To optimize the generated swf size, the flex compiler does not package the classes that are never referenced in the project (this is what I have been told but I cannot find any reference of that in the documentation).

I am wondering if there is a way to have the list of excluded items.

This list would helps me to cleanup my project and remove unused resources

I had a look to the link report but it lists the included files. Is there a way to generate the list of excluded items (mxml, as, assets, ...).

*Note: I know I could parse the link-report and compare it against my project files, but there is probably an easiest and mor efficient way... I hope...*

Comment: A good IDE (i.e. not FlashBuilder) can tell you which classes are unused.

Comment: Well, I'd like an automated and IDE independent process. BTW, I am using intelliJ 12 but it does not tell me which mxml files are not used in the project

Comment: Yes it does: Analyze > Inspect code. Results will be under: Global > unused ActionScript global symbol

Comment: Does not work with MXML from a module

Answer (score 0):

You could give [FlexPMD](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexpmd/home/Home/) a try. Its intended for such purposes.